# How do I do simple multithreading in Isabelle ML?

Tags: isabelle

I've found a use for wanting to start multiple `Isabelle_System.bash` processes.

In this next source, I use 3 `bash` commands. For a simple example, I would like to start them in separate threads, so that they run concurrently, rather than sequentially.

```
ML {*
 Isabelle_System.bash ("echo '1. Call script to compile in the PIDE console.'");
 Isabelle_System.bash ("echo '2. Call script to compile in a Windows console.'");
 Isabelle_System.bash ("echo '3. Maybe a third process.'");
 (*In an outer syntax command, I have options to allow 1 and 2, so it might be 
   useful to allow starting both at the same time, to be able to terminate the 
   PIDE process, and let the Windows console keep running. But, unless  
   multithreading is used, their execution will be sequential, which is 
   useless.*)
*}
```

I did a grep, and I've found [`src/Pure/Concurrent/simple_thread.ML`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Concurrent/simple_thread.ML).

However, this is not a priority, and it wouldn't be best for me to use trial-and-error to try and figure out what needs to be done on my own.

If someone can give me a simple plug-n-play template to run the 3 bash commands above, I would appreciate it. Or, maybe someone can tell me why I can't or shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Simple multithreading" is an oxymoron, because threads are never simple.  If you just want to do parallel programming, which is simple, then the first place to look is the structure `Par_List`, e.g. the `Par_List.map` combinator.  In the [Isabelle/Isar Implementation Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf) there is a section on "Parallel skeletons" about it, and more information in the vicinity.

Comment: Makarius, generally it's best not to bite the hand that feeds me, but... Here, you're making a casual comment, or you're lecturing me on language. I take it as a lecture, since you do that with language. You choose language that leads people to think a certain way (the main problem being that you choose what already has widespread meaning), and then you tell people not to think that way. It's like telling a dog not to wag his tail. You named the structure SIMPLE_THREAD. I sometimes make attempts to conform, even when I disagree. As a novice, I followed the lead of a pro. Look what happened.

Comment: I now see that the name of the internal Simple_Thread structure could lead to confusion.  It was motivated as a slightly simplified wrapper over the underlying Thread structures, both in ML and on the JVM.  As a rule of thumb, when one discovers something potentially useful, a quick hypersearch for its typical uses gives an impression about its relevance for applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fill in a few details, based on Makarius Wenzel's answer.

It turns out, that with the Isabelle/ML library in src/Pure, running parallel, independent bash processes is extraordinarily easy:

```
ML {* (*Running this multiple times shows the order of execution varies.*)
  Par_List.map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list;
  val bash_strings = [
    "echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.' ", 
    "echo 'Bash 2, bro!'", 
    "echo 'Bash 3, hombre or señorita!'", 
    "echo 'Bash 4, dude!'"];
  val _ = Par_List.map Isabelle_System.bash bash_strings
*} (*
OUTPUT:
  Bash 4, dude! 
  Bash 2, bro! 
  Bash 3, hombre or señorita! 
  Echo 1.
  Echo 1.
  Echo 1.
  Echo 1. 
  val it = fn: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
  val bash_strings =
     ["echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.'; echo 'Echo 1.' ",
      "echo 'Bash 2, bro!'", "echo 'Bash 3, hombre or señorita!'",
      "echo 'Bash 4, dude!'"]:
     string list*)
```

A 5 minute solution to a multi-month implementation problem, not counting the overhead of asking the question, reading the answer, opening the PDF, firing up the PIDE, and typing various stuff before locking onto some source that shows a simple example that works.

- [Section 0.9.1 Parallel skeletons, *The Isabelle/Isar Implementation*, Isabelle2014 (PDF)](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2014/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf#page.39)
- [src/Pure/par_list.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Concurrent/par_list.ML)